# Add library project as dependency to another library project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have been trying to add a library project as a dependency to another library project in Android Studio without success.  Below is my project structure:

```
- apps
  - demo (depends on android utilities & android ui)
- libraries
  - android utilities
    - utilities
  - android ui
    - ui (depends on android utilities)
```

I used the following as guide
[Add local Library Project as a dependency to multiple Projects in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149690/add-local-library-project-as-a-dependency-to-multiple-projects-in-android-studio)

### android utilities/build.gradle

```
...
```

### android utilities/utilities/build.gradle

```
apply plugin 'com.android.library'

...
```

### android ui/settings.gradle

```
include ':ui'
include ':utilities'
project(':utilities').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../android utilities/utilities')
```

### android ui/build.gradle

```
...
```

### android ui/ui/build.gradle

```
apply plugin 'com.android.library'

...

dependencies {
    compile project(':utilities')
}
```

I have both *Android Utilities* and *Android Ui* setup as separate projects, I am able to compile the *Android Utilities* project without issues. But, I am not able to compile the separate *Android Ui* project. Android Studio itself doesn't indicate any errors, but gradle produces multiple errors about packages from the utilities library not existing.

Comment: Does utilities contain a build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to reflect that those files do exist, however, if you think it would be better to include all the contents of the gradle files I can definitely do that.

Comment: It seems correct. Did you try to run gradle clean?

Comment: I did, executing "Build\Clean Project" from the IDE gives me the same errors as when I attempt to build. I have to run gradlew clean from the command line in order to get a successful clean. But, cleaning doesn't seem to help either. I have also tried recreating the projects from scratch in a new folder. I appreciate the help as I feel like it is something simple that I am just overlooking.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to this issue, the only work around that came up with was to push the library to my own private maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in my project but managed to resolve it. Do you have more than 1 ***build flavor***?

What I ended up doing is adding following in library (**/ui/ui/build.gradle** in your case), where **buildFlavor1** and **buildFlavor2** - are build variants used in your app. I think the problem was because Gradle is not aware of possible configurations when resolving dependencies, so he cannot properly pick the library for every build flavor. Hope this helps!

```
configurations {
    buildFlavor1DebugCompile
    buildFlavor2DebugCompile
    buildFlavor1ReleaseCompile
    buildFlavor2ReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
    ...

    buildFlavor1DebugCompile project(path: ':utilities', configuration: 'buildFlavor1Debug')
    buildFlavor2DebugCompile project(path: ':utilities', configuration: 'buildFlavor2Debug')
    buildFlavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':utilities', configuration: 'buildFlavor1Release')
    buildFlavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':utilities', configuration: 'buildFlavor2Release')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the right syntax. This:

```
include 'ui'
```

should be this:

```
include ':ui'
```

(you missed the colon)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, unfortunately, that was just an oversight on my part, the actual settings.gradle file does include the colon.  I have corrected the sample.