# Add (external) local library project as dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to add a local library project that I cloned (and modified a bit) from Github ([Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)) as a dependency to my application.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176418/166229) it should be as easy as:

`settings.gradle`

```
include(':reactivelocation')
project(':reactivelocation').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation')
```

`build.gradle` in my app directory

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':reactivelocation')
}
```

Unfortunately I get the error

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

As soon as I add the `compile` statement. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to use `compile project(':reactivelocation:android-reactive-location')` as I am only interested in this module library inside `Android-ReactiveLocation`, but this also fails

> Project with path ':reactivelocation:android-reactive-location' could
>   not be found in project.

**Update. Some other things I tried without success (same error):**

`settings.gradle`

```
include(':android-reactive-location')
project(':android-reactive-location').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation/android-reactive-location')
```

`build.gradle` in my app diretory

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':android-reactive-location')
}
```

---

`settings.gradle`

```
include(':Android-ReactiveLocation')
project(':Android-ReactiveLocation').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation')
```

`build.gradle` in my app diretory

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':Android-ReactiveLocation')
}
```

---

`settings.gradle`

```
include(':Android-ReactiveLocation:android-reactive-location')
project(':Android-ReactiveLocation:android-reactive-location').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation/') // also with '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation/android-reactive-location'
```

`build.gradle` in my app diretory

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':Android-ReactiveLocation:android-reactive-location')
}
```

Comment: Why did you clone the library? https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation#how-to-use-it

Comment: Do develop that library further in the context of my app. I can then directly manipulate that library and see how it behaves in my app. Makes development of both much easier.

Comment: Did you try `:Android-ReactiveLocation:android-reactive-location`?

Comment: Yep (see edit above) ... same error.

Comment: What is the output of ./gradlew tasks ?

Comment: @jonathanrz I uploaded [the output of `gradle -info` to Gist](https://gist.github.com/medihack/10c80e19a1b531c2ec4def709c94a80b).

Comment: @Zardoz run with --stacktrace please

Comment: @jonathanrz [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/medihack/1e727244727db009a652233ec8650832), not very informative :-/

Comment: @Zardoz the module android-reactive-location has a build.gradle file in the module root directory? Looking for the error, it seems that gradle can´t find a way to build the module.

Comment: @Zardoz I believe that this answer has info that can be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar scenario in my project. In `build.gradle` in `app` directory you should add `path` before the library name:

```
compile project(path: ':reactivelocation')
```

In my project every things work whit above line. My `settings.gradle` is exactly like yours.

Comment: Nope, the error remains (my version is just a shortcut). I guess it has something to do with how [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) is set up. It contains a subfolder (`android-reactive-location`) were the real library lives. Unfortunately it is not possible to use this folder as `projectDir` directly as the [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/android-reactive-location/build.gradle) depends on stuff in the root (e.g. see `compileSdkVersion` in that file).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here. But, are you aware that the directory you listed in the settings, might have a typo?

```
include(':reactivelocation')
project(':reactivelocation').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Andrdoid-ReactiveLocation')
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps this should be, as the project you have cloned named, `Android-ReactiveLocation`