# Add dependency of a locally built library?

Tags: android, dependencies, shared-libraries, local

I could use a little help better understanding the options I have with regards to adding a dependency on an Android library that has been published locally.

In my situation, I have two different projects located in two different directories:

```
Project of Library: ~/Documents/src/<my library>
Project that will consume library: ~/Documents/src/<client app>
```

I followed the instructions provided here in order to publish the android library locally:

http://blog.maxaller.name/android/2016/11/25/developing-a-local-android-plugin.html

I'm going to assume that the output library generated ended up here:

```
~/Documents/src/<my library>/library/build/outputs/aar/*.aar
```

It'd be nice if I can point directly to this library.

What options do I have in order to update the build.gradle file of the client app such that there is a dependency on that library?

Below is the key pieces of the build.gradle file, as it currently stands:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
        }
...

dependencies {
... 
   ???implementation <my group ID>:<my artifact ID>:<version #>??

   OR

    implementation project(path: '<What am I doing?>')
...
}
```

I must troubleshoot a few things before publishing the library online.

Thanks for the clarification in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149690/add-local-library-project-as-a-dependency-to-multiple-projects-in-android-studio) is helpful?

Comment: Thanks for that link. That is part of what is required. Go ahead and provide an "answer", and I'll check off your answer. 

It looks like I can import that *.aar file using Android Studio, which will automatically included those lines into my gradle file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst

Comment: You're welcome! but I think it's better (for others in the same situation) if you write down how you managed to solve the whole problem.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank God for Source Control! I can actually review my own work!

Comment: [Stack Overflow's point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on answering one's own question. BTW, the reviewing will be done by everyone who does [not] vote on your question or your answer. Your accepting your own answer just says it worked for you, case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that there are options to solve my problem.

I like Option # 1:

I. From the top menu: File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR ->
    Follow subsequent instructions.

A few things will automatically be done for you:

- The folder named after the *.aar selected will be created.
- A build.gradle file will also be created inside that folder.
- Your library will automatically be added to the directory.
- Your module will be added to the settings.gradle file.

II. Track down the build.gradle of your client app and add this line:

```
implementation project(':<Your Module Name>')
```

Given the circumstances of the client app I was working on, I was forced to add that dependency in two different modules.

Reference:
[How to add .aar dependency in library module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765190/how-to-add-aar-dependency-in-library-module)

Option # 2: I can't confirm this approach, but it looks like another acceptable solution.

[How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)